# How to use custom soundfonts in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, quicktime, midi, sound-font

In previous OSX versions I could put custom SF2 soundfonts into ~/Library/Audio/Sounds/Banks and then select which soundbank to use in Quicktime. After upgrading to Snow Leopard I noticed that Quicktime 7 (Quicktime X doesn't play MIDI) is missing a preferences pane where to select the soundbank. Is there a way to use soundfonts in OSX 10.6 or ask a workaround, is there a free software synth for OSX that supports SF2 soundfonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered that newer versions of VLC (looks like 1.1.7 and higher) support MIDI and SoundFonts on Snow Leopard:

http://www.videolan.org/

I've tested several dozen MIDIs with the old Creative SoundFonts and it works great.

I'm responding to this old question since it's in the top 3 Google results for "snow leopard sound fonts". Hope it helps someone else out.

Comment: I guess this might be the best option, unfortunately doesn't help with cases where I am using app that uses Quicktime to play midi.